# Returning an enumeration of events on particular date

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a function that returns an enumeration of 'appointment' items that consists of the following code -

```
public interface IAppointment
{
    DateTime Start { get; }
    int Length { get; }
    string DisplayableDescription { get; }
    bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date);
}
```

The function is supposed to retrieve 'Appointments' Items out of a list.  I have instanced the list at the top of class that is accessed globally by all methods implemented from IList interface.

Here is my function so far

```
public IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date)
{
    foreach (IAppointment item in _list)
    {
        if(item.Start.Date == date.Date)
        {
            return item; //  error appears here under 'item'
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'....IAppointment'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<...IAppointment>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my assignment spec for this function: `GetAppointmentsOnDate` - retrieves an *enumeration* of all of the appointments that occur on the *specified date*.

Comment: FYI, if `Length` is meant to be the duration of the appointment you might want to consider using `TimeSpan` instead of `int`.  That way you don't have to guess what units are and it should make time calculations easier.

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to use timespan, however my programming confidence is pretty low and I'm afraid it may wreck the rest of the 'predone' code in some of the other classes

Comment: Also note that if `date` is just the day the appointment occurs on and `Start` is the date and the time when the appointment starts you'll want to do `item.Start.Date == date`, or maybe even `item.Start.Date == date.Date` in case the `date` has a time.  The `Date` property basically returns a `DateTime` with the same date, but the time set to midnight.

Comment: Great. Thankyou.  I'm guessing that narrow it down to the actual day and not the time?

Answer (score 4):

Use yield keyword:

```
public IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date)
    {

        foreach (IAppointment item in _list)
        {
            if(item.Start == date)
            {
                yield return item;  
            }
        }

    }
```

Or just use Where to achieve your condition (don't forget to include `import System.Linq;`):

```
_list.Where(item=>item.Start == date);
```

Answer (score 2):

> The function is supposed to retrieve an 'Appointment' Item out of a
>   list.

You are trying to return an `IEnumerable<IAppointment>` which would be a collection of appointments, but from the code and description it looks like that you want to return a single item, change your return type to `IAppointment` in your method.

You can also use `FirstOrDefault` like:

```
public IAppointment GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date)
{
   return _list.FirstOrDefault(item=> item.Start == date);
}
```

---

From the name of your functions it appears that you want to get all appointments for a particular date, in that case you can do:

```
public IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date)
{
   return _list.Where(item=> item.Start == date);
}
```

or in your particular code you can use [`yield`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=yield%20C%23) keyword with return

```
public IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date)
{

    foreach (IAppointment item in _list)
    {
        if (item.Start == date)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use the following to retrieve appointments for current date:

```
foreach (var appointments in GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime.Now))
{

}
```

As @Alexei Levenkov pointed out, if you want to get Appointments for a particular `Date` *(ignoring time)* then use the `DateTime.Date` property like `GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime.Now.Date)` or `GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime.Today)`

Comment: The fact that the method is called `GetAppointmentsOnDate` makes it sound like it should be returning more than one.  But the intention of the OP is a bit muddled here.

Comment: While it is indeed a solution to compile time error, name of the function suggests collection return type ("GetAppointment**s**OnDate")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes name does sound like the OP wanted multiple appointments, I missed that, but the description is also very explicit "retrieve an 'Appointment' Item out of a list.", I will modify my answer.

Comment: This is my assignment spec for this function - 

GetAppointmentsOnDate -   Retrieves an enumeration of all of the appointments that occur on the 
specified date.

However, I have no idea how to do this

Comment: @Ely, modify your question to say that as well, currently in your question description it appears that you are looking to get a single Appointment, I have modified my answer to return all appointments for a particular date.

Comment: @Habib Nice update! Consider to use `DateTime.Date` in sample to have code completely aligned with function name.

Comment: foreach (var appointments in GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime.Now))

Do I need this line of code for the function to work?  I do not undestand it.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: @Ely, that is just an example how the function will work, it depends on you, how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is `IEnumerable<IAppointment>` but you are trying to return `IAppointment`. That's going to stop it compiling, I would have thought...